# Separate the last three number of my code

Tags: sql-server

I have been working with SQL Server 2008 and I have a big table but one of my colums is "CODE" and I need to separate it in 2 parts, the last 3 numbers I need to show it in another column, how can I do it?

```
CODE
R501001003002
R501001003004
R501001003005
R501001003006
R501001003009
```

The result that I want to show is something like this

```
CODE                FINALCODE
R501001003          002
R501001003          004
R501001003          005
R501001003          006
R501001003          009
```

Comment: are the values in the CODE field always the same length?

Answer (score 3):

The following simple SQL should give you what you need:-

```
SELECT 
  LEFT([CODE],10) as [CODE], 
  RIGHT([CODE],3) as FINALCODE
FROM YourTable
```